# How to write multiple Google Cloud Function in one repository

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I need to deploy multiple functions in Google Cloud Functions with one repository (from Google Cloud) and using Express in NodeJS.

Is possible to achieve this?

I have two different modules (checkout, customer) and an index:

**checkout.js**

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 *
 *
 */
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const checkout = express();

checkout.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const PORT = 5555;
checkout.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

const COMMENTS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John1',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];

checkout.get('/comments', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(process.env.TEST || 33);
}, function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.json(err);
});

checkout.get('/:commentId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS.find(comment => comment.id === parseInt(req.params.commentId)));
});

module.exports = checkout;
```

**customer.js**

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 *
 *
 */

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const customer = express();

customer.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const PORT = 5555;
customer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

const USERS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];

customer.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS);
});

customer.get('/:userId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS.find(user => user.id === parseInt(req.params.userId)));
});

module.exports = customer;
```

How i can import those module in inde.js?

If i add like this the function doesn't return the response:

```
const checkout = require('./checkout');
const customer = require('./customer');

module.require = {
    checkout,
    customer
};
```

Comment: This isn't going to work no matter how you export things.  You can't listen on a port in Cloud Functions.  That part is managed for you.  All you can deploy is your routes.

Comment: @DougStevenson how i can export my different routes for different google cloud functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all functions you need to deploy to index.js
Then export each function.

Each function you export will be deployed to cloud functions.

Comment: Yes but how i can do this? I've added more code to explain.